# CKEditor 4.13 - Which core or plugin are the styles (div.xyz) coming from?

Tags: ckeditor

In my CKEditor instance, I am seeing formatting styles added that start with div. (i.e. div.dataTables_xyz, div.dt-button-xyz, div.dtr-modal-xyz.) How can I find out which plugin is adding them? (or if it's core ckeditor, how can I remove them?)

Tried removing several plugins that I thought might be the culprit (i.e. Div Editing Area, Div Container Manager)

I would prefer not to have those styles listed, as they are numerous and will likely confuse our users.

Answer (score 1):

the plugin was stylesheet parser. 
https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/stylesheetparser